# How to Rebuild Text Files with php

Tags: php, text

Hello i have text list files as below.

```
0  // means Type
0 1 1 "Kris" 
1 1 1 "Short Sword" 
2 1 1 "Rapier" 
3 1 1 "Katache" 
4 1 1 "Scimitar" 
5 1 1 "Blade" 
6 1 1 "Gladius" 
end // end of first type


1 // type
0 1 1 "Small Axe" 
1 1 1 "Hand Axe" 
2 1 1 "Double Axe" 
3 1 1 "Tomahawk" 
4 1 1 "Fairy Axe" 
end // end of 2nd type
```

goes on more than 1000 lines. the question is how can i rebuild tham escaping empty lines and "end" words and put first line to as a type number like bellow

```
0 0 1 1 "Kris" 
0 1 1 1 "Short Sword" 
0 2 1 1 "Rapier" 
0 3 1 1 "Katache" 
0 4 1 1 "Scimitar" 
0 5 1 1 "Blade" 
0 6 1 1 "Gladius" 
1  0 1 1 "Small Axe" 
1  1 1 1 "Hand Axe" 
1  2 1 1 "Double Axe" 
1  3 1 1 "Tomahawk"
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please show what you've tried. We'll help you fix your code, but we're not going to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about preformance at all and just want to rebuild the file open the file using `file("path")`, that reads the whole file inn as an array. 
Go through the array and read everything before the double quote. Strip all the whitespace and convert it into an integer. Then check if that value is the largest value, if it is store it. 
Then use the largest value you have and add approprite 0 you want.

Try this:

```
$file = file("test.txt");

$bigValue = 0; 

foreach($file as &$value) 
{
   $end = strpos($value, '"'); 

    if($end !== false) 
    {
         $subStr = substr($value, 0, $end);

         $subStr = trim($subStr, " ");

         $value = $subStr . substr($value, $end, strlen($value)); 

         if(intval($subStr) > $bigValue)
             $bigValue = intval($subStr); 

    }
}

echo $bigValue; 

//add the 0.
foreach($file as &$value) 
{
    $end = strpos($value, '"'); 

    if($end !== false)
    {
        $subStr = substr($value, 0, $end);

        $zero = ""; 

        if(strlen($subStr) < $bigValue)
        {
            for($x = 0; $x < ($bigValue- strlen($subStr)); $x++)
            {
                $zero .= "0"; 
            }
        }

        $subStr = $zero . $subStr; 
        $newStr = "";

        //add the spaces. 
        for($x = 0; $x < strlen($subStr); $x++)
        {
            $newStr .= $subStr{$x} . " "; 
        }

        $value = $newStr . substr($value, $end, strlen($value)); 
    }

}


print_r($file);
```